# Parent VeiwControllers of ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My main view PlayGameViewController has a subview (actually 2 of them) called CardViewController.

CardViewController creates some buttons programmatically

```
  -(void) initialiseButtons 
  {
    NSLog(@"initialiseButtons  %d",totalButtons);
    int ypos = playerImage.frame.origin.y + playerImage.frame.size.height + 42;
    for(int i=0; i<totalButtons; i++) 
    {       
        StatView *sv = [[StatView alloc] initWithYPos:ypos];
        sv.tag = 100 + i;
        [sv.overlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(statTapped:) 
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        sv.overlayButton.tag = 10 + i;
        [self.frontView addSubview:sv];
        ypos += 26;
    }
  }
```

It sets a callback function statTapped. This works ok and the function does get called.
But... All the game logic is in PlayGameViewController so I need to handle the function there. I tried deleting the function from CardViewController and implementing it instead in the PlayGameViewController but the call wasn't passed down to the parent class.

Is there away to achieve this or am I talking and thinking crazy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a couple of options:

1. Create a delegate to process your `statTapped:` method. You can learn more about delegates and how to create one here: [How do I create delegates in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)
2. Use `NSNotification` and add a listener in `PlayGameViewController` that will call the `statTapped:` method (also defined in `PlayGameViewController`. Then in `CardViewController` have your selector action call a method that posts a notification. `PlayGameViewController` will receive that notification and then run the specified tasks.

Here is an example of using `NSNotification`:

In your `PlayGameViewController`'s init method, write:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(statTapped:) 
                                             name:@"statTapped"
                                           object:nil];
```

In `CardViewController`, you'll want to set a selector to your button action as you do now, but instead of `statTapped:` you'll want a different method which contains this code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"statTapped" 
                                                    object:self];
```

By doing so your `PlayGameController` will own the `statTapped` method.

Don't forget to remove the observer in your `viewDidUnload` method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"statTapped" object:nil];
```

Comment: Ok i follow you as far as setting up the NSNotification center in PlayGameViewController. The second line is code : [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"statTapped" object:self]; Does that get called from within my startTapped method inside CardViewController? Then finally I implement a method called startTapped inside PlayGameViewController which will be called as a result of all the above code.